# ios right align uilable but second line left align

Tags: ios, uilabel

I have multiline UILable. I want it to be right align. But second line inside must be left align.

Here is picture. Label contains email id. Last two characters `"om"` are going on second line. I want this to start below `"durga.."`

[image]

Comment: set the number of line to `1`, for example.

Comment: If I set number of lines to 1, I will get only one line. I want it to be multiline.

Comment: Are you using Autolayout for the label ?

Comment: Yes. Autolayout is used.

Comment: you got solution for what you have asked bro?I need the same solution now, can I get some help on it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the Label's textAlignment attribute to `NSTextAlignmentLeft`.
2. Make the LineBreakMode to `NSLineBreakByCharWrapping`.
3. Make the Label's width constraint to fit the content, and set the Right Margin constraint as you wish. (Alternatively, calculate the label's size according to the content and position it where you need).

The Label then will cut the text and start a new line in the left side.

Answer (score 0):

judge whether width of the string is less than width of the label
if yes, make it right align. otherwise make it left align.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Autolayout for the label just constraint the label horizontally and vertically to what ever view it is in also fix it's width so that it can be wrapped. [image]

then make sure you have label's lines set to 2[image]

and finally set line breaks to "Character Wrap" [image]

[image]

Comment: not working, I have given the same constraints but text is showing from right side only

Comment: Have you fixed the width ?

Comment: You have to give a certain fixed width